# Order state when creating shipping label

Tags: magento-1.8, order-status, order-state

I have created a script that automatically create UPS shipping labels when a certain orders have the status "ready_for_ups".

However I'm unsure to which "state" I should assign this to. Is it "pending" or "processing".

Almost all of our payments are done with credit card and a few with bank wire transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pending = not paid yet
- Processing = Paid not shipped/Shipped not paid

So I would go with processing

Comment: Thank you. I will use that one.

As for order status. I was thinking of adding them similiar to the ones I currently have in Opencart. That is Pending, Complete, Ready for UPS, Shipped and Cancelled. Guess that wouldn't be a problem as long as the States are there.